# MySQL Workbench and foreign keys -- not a happy marriage

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench prevents me from setting up a foreign key.  I'm using the INNO-DB database engine.

I have 4 tables that I'd like to be linked to the same  user id number.  I've broken up the data into these tables in hopes that it will be more efficient not opening up the whole database to work on different parts of the project that don't require the whole data set.

But, no matter what settings I try, I can't get it to accept a foreign key.  It always gives me errors when running the SQL. 
I'm wondering if this is Workbench being over zealous, or if I'm missing something.

Is there a tutorial around that shows how to do this?  The MySQL info is very bleak and assumes everything is going to work.  Or perhaps someone that would be interested in a quick consulting job to help me get this set up?

Comment: "It always gives me errors…" It'd be helpful to know what those errors are, exactly. Post a screenshot if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work in MySQL 5.0.  Here's how:

Do some set-up - create a database and a user; GRANT user permissions:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
create database foreign_demo;
create user foreign_demo identified by 'foreign_demo';
grant all on foreign_demo.* to 'foreign_demo'@'%';
grant all on foreign_demo.* to 'foreign_demo'@'localhost';
```

Now create two simple tables: t1 (parent) and t2 (child):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1
(
    t1_id integer not null auto_increment,
    primary key(t1_id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t2
(
    t2_id integer not null auto_increment,
    t1_id integer,
    primary key(t1_id),
    constraint fk_t1 foreign key(t2_id) references t1(t1_id) on delete cascade on update cascade
);
```

Now let's insert a row into each:

```
INSERT INTO t1 values();
INSERT INTO t2(t1_id) SELECT last_insert_id();
```

Let's select what just got inserted:

```
select * from t1;
select * from t2;
```

You should see one row in each table; the `t2` table will refer to the `t1`.

Now delete the parent record:

```
delete from t1 where t1_id = 1;
```

When you run these selects you should find no rows in either table, because deleting the parent cascades to a delete in the child table:

```
select * from t1;
select * from t2;
```

Better?

Comment: I haven't figured out how to get the chart thing to work yet, but here's what the sql looks like:

ALTER TABLE `bizzocalldev`.`buttonprefs` 

  ADD CONSTRAINT `iduserid`

  FOREIGN KEY ()

  REFERENCES `bizzocalldev`.`userinfo` ()

  ON DELETE CASCADE

  ON UPDATE CASCADE

, ADD INDEX `iduserid` () ;

But it doesn't run.  I get error these errors:

Comment: these errors:

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

  REFERENCES `bizzocalldev`.`userinfo` ()

  ON DELETE CASCADE

  ON UPDATE CASC' at line 3

SQL Statement:

ALTER TABLE `bizzocalldev`.`buttonprefs` ...


ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
ERROR 1046: No database selected
SQL Statement:

CREATE TABLE `buttonprefs` (

  `bleft` int(2) default NULL,...

  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: Aha!  I created 2 new tables and linked them up.  No errors.  But it doesn't behave as I'd expected.  I added 3 records to the main table, and I thought that 3 empty records would be created automatically in the linked table.  But nothing happened!  I did have the "cascade" turned on....

Comment: The output I posted was from MySQL Workbench itself; try fixing them and see if it eventually works.  Your expectations might be the thing that's wrong.

Comment: That's probably true.  Am I mistaken in interpreting "cascade" to mean that an addition or deletion from the primary database will result in the same thing happening to the linked database?  If so, how DO I make this happen, other than manually writing sql to do it?

Comment: No, it means that if you delete the parent record the child that points to it will be removed as well.  Tables are linked IF you use the MySQL InnoDB engine.  Not so if you don't.

Comment: I'm using InnoDB.  OK, I tested this and its true.  Hmm. I fail to see the usefulness of foreign keys if this is all they do.  How can I make a child database add a record when the parent adds a record, with the same key number in both?  So far, when I try this, the child that is added gets its own number, not related to the parent.  Weird....

Comment: You keep saying "database"; I think you should be thinking "table".  You're misunderstanding what happens when a child record is inserted.  Adding a child is a multi-step process: (1) Add the parent, with its auto incremented primary key; (2) Get the primary key of the parent, (3) Insert the child, with its auto incremented primary key, and set the foreign key to equal the parent's primary key.  It's not "weird"; how do expect the child to magically know its parent?  What if it's possible to add a child without a parent (null foreign key)?  It's your understanding that's flawed here.

Comment: I guess I'm just missing it.  Would you be interested in doing some consulting work, paid by the hour?  I really need to crack this little problem. Let me know....

Comment: I saw it.  I'm working on a test now to see if I can understand it.

Comment: Just run exactly what I posted - it demonstrates my understanding exactly.

Comment: $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO testtable (firstname, lastname) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['firstname'], "text"),

 $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO linktable (idlinktable) VALUES (%s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_COOKIE['sessuserid'], "int"));
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['lastname'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_bizCon, $bizCon);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $bizCon) or die(mysql_error());
}

--where column idlinktable is the foreign key linked to the first table

Comment: I get this error:

I get this error:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bizzocalldev/linktable`, CONSTRAINT `iduserid` FOREIGN KEY (`idlinktable`) REFERENCES `testtable` (`iduserid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: I had to leave out all lines except the queries because of the limitations of the comment window...I hope it still makes sense.

Comment: I just noticed that you added some code to one of your earlier posts.  Sorry I missed that.  I'll try to run it...

Comment: OK.  I see the action now.  What I'm doing wrong is to have the foreign key of the second database using the same column as the primary key. Apparently it needs to be a different column.  I'll try implementing this in my actual columns now.